# Alternative solution for custom Vtype?

Tags: extjs

i was trying to use a Custom Vtype in my program. Here many tried to help me. But i could not get much benefit from those. This was my code.

```
Ext.apply(Ext.form.VTypes, {
password: function(val, field) {
if (field.initialPassField) {
var pwd = Ext.getCmp(field.initialPassField);
return (val == pwd.getValue());
}
return true;
},
passwordText: 'What are you doing?<br/>The passwords entered
do not match!'
});
```

I included this code in "launch" function of Application and changed vtype to 'password'. it worked.is it the right method? however i got the result. If im wrong and some other method is available please inform me. This is my launch function in Application.

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
enabled: true
});

Ext.application({
views: [
'signupForm'
],
autoCreateViewport: true,
name: 'MyApp',

launch: function() {
Ext.apply(Ext.form.VTypes, {
password: function(val, field) {
if (field.initialPassField) {
var pwd = Ext.getCmp(field.initialPassField);
return (val == pwd.getValue());
}
return true;
},
passwordText: 'What are you doing?<br/>The passwords entered do not match!'
});
}

});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find your answer in the following code.

```
Ext.onReady(function() {    
    Ext.apply(Ext.form.VTypes, {
        password: function(val, field) {
            if (field.initialPassField) {
                var pwd = field.up('form').getForm().findField("initialPassField");
                return (val == pwd.getValue());
            }
            return true;
        },
        passwordText: 'What are you doing?<br/>The passwords entered do not match!'
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        title: 'Simple Form',
        bodyPadding: 5,
        width: 350,
        height : 400,

        defaultType: 'textfield',
        items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'First Name',
            name: 'first',
            allowBlank: false
        },{
            fieldLabel: 'Password',
            name: 'last',
            initialPassField : true,
            vtype : 'password',
            inputType : 'password',
            allowBlank: false
        }, {
            name: 'initialPassField',
            hidden : true,
            value : 'Ajith'
        }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
});
```

Writing custom VType is the best way to validate form fields.

Comment: Hi Siva Kumar, I wanted to do the exact way of in your code. But i couldn't understand "Ext.onReady(function() {    
    Ext.apply(Ext.form.VTypes, {" this part. so did in that way.Still i dont know how to do as you mentioned. I need how and where i should include my "password function ".

Comment: You can include your VType code in beforerender event as in http://jsfiddle.net/hWGYE/2904/

Comment: Ajith, when you get the answer you want, give a up vote, this will add rep and will make the answer more appealing to the question in future

Comment: hi strikers, did u mean i should press that up arrow which is displayed in the left side? and it shows i dont have enough reputation. i will do it k. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can override `Ext.form.field.VTypes`. Since that's a singleton, that will indeed modify the `Ext.form.field.VTypes` object directly, and not its prototype (i.e. `Ext.form.field.VTypes.prototype`).

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Ext.form.field.VTypes', {
    override: 'Ext.form.field.VTypes'
    ,test: function() {
        // ...
    }
    ,testText: '...'
});
```

The advantage of doing so is that the class loader will be able to manage this override like a standard class. That is, you can require your override, in your application definition or anywhere else. For example:

```
Ext.application({
    requires: [
        'MyApp.Ext.form.field.VTypes'
    ]
    // ...
});
```

**Update**

Here's what it would give with your code.

First, create the file `app/VTypes.js`:

```
// I've simplified the class name, compared to above    
Ext.define('MyApp.VTypes', {
    override: 'Ext.form.field.VTypes' // <= this is the line that makes it an override

    ,password: function(val, field) {
        if (field.initialPassField) {
            var pwd = Ext.getCmp(field.initialPassField);
            return (val == pwd.getValue());
        }
        return true;
    }

    ,passwordText: 'What are you doing?<br/>The passwords entered do not match!'
});
```

Then, require it in your application definition (i.e. `app.js`):

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp'
    ,requires: [
        'MyApp.VTypes'
    ]
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Hi Rixo,Actually I dont know how to override properly. For RowExpander once i did that. That time i just pressed "create override" of "MygridPanel"(UserClassName) and typed my code.In Vtype case can you tell me what i should do exactly to override. Sorry to ask this stupid question.

Comment: See my updated answer. I've never used Architect, so I cannot give you more detailed instructions for it...